# Error in my project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I was making this little app to practice SpringMVC, but I am keep getting this error. I wanted to see if anybody can point out where I am doing wrong. I see this error is coming from EmployeeDao.jsp, but I coudn't figure out what I am doing wrong, or what causes this error. I appreciate any suggestion.  [image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home of XYZ Inc.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Welcome to my XYZ Inc company. 
</h1>

<P> <a href="viewEmployee">View All Employee</a> </P>


</body>
</html>
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
    List<Employee> employees;
    employees = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
    try {
        Statement statement;
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery("select * from Employees");
        while(rset.next()) {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setEmployeeId(rset.getInt("employeeId"));
            employee.setName(rset.getString("name"));
            employee.setTittle(rset.getString("tittle"));
            employee.setHourlyWage(rset.getString("hourlyWage"));
            employee.setTotalHour(rset.getString("totalHour"));
            employees.add(employee);
        }

    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return employees;
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/viewEmployee")
public ModelAndView viewEmployee() {
    List<Employee> list = dao.getAllEmployee();
    return new ModelAndView("viewEmployee", "list", list);
}
```

Comment: Which one is line #68 in EmployeeDao.java?

Comment: check your `connection` object if it is not null

Comment: yes, your `connection` object is not initialized

Comment: Don't show code in a comment. Edit the question and add code. Delete the comment.

Comment: Then `DbUtil.getConnection()` returned `null`, or some other constructor was called.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/, e.g. putting breakpoint on line 68 and on line assigning `connection`, to verify value is assigned.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have put breakpoint on line 68 and ran on debug, and I see: value is null in connection. is that mean I am not getting connected to the database I have created for it?